# quickly (XOR-?) combine SHA1 hashes to generate a new hash

Tags: javascript, hash, sha1

Having a (possibly large) list of **unique** text lines (stringified JSON data) I need to calculate a unique hash for the whole text document. Often new lines are appended to the document and occasionally some lines will be deleted from it, resulting into a completely new hash for the document.

**The ultimate goal is to be able to identify identical documents just using the hash.**

Of course, calculating the SHA1 hash for the whole document after each modification would give me the desired unique hash, but would also be **computationally expensive** - especially in a situation where just ~40 bytes are appended to a 5 megabyte document and all that data would have to go through the SHA1 calculation again.

So, I'm looking into a solution that allows me to reduce the time it takes to calculate the new hash.

A summary of the problem properties / requirements:

- each line is guaranteed to be unique
- the order of the lines does **not necessarily** need to matter (even better if it doesn't)
- the length of a single line is usually small, but the whole document might be large
- the algorithm can be optimized for *appended* data (i.e. deleting data might even require a restart from scratch in such a case)

My current idea is to calculate the SHA1 (or whatever) hash for each single line individually and then **XOR the hashes** together. That should satisfy all requirements. For new lines I just calculate the SHA1 of that line and XOR it with the already known sum.

However, I'm in doubt because...

- I 'm not sure if the XORed hash would still be strong enough to exactly identify a document (ie. is there a significantly higher probability of unwanted collisions?)
- calculating lots of SHA1 hashes of short lines might be computationally expensive of it's own (at least during initialization)

Anybody can shed some light into these issues?

Alternatively, is it perhaps generally possible with SHA1 (or a similar hash) to quickly generate a new hash for appended data (`old hash` + `appended data` = `new hash`)?

Comment: What `sha1` js implementation are you use?

Comment: The implementation should not matter for this question as it doesn't even need to be SHA1 as long as the hash is strong enough to "uniquely" identify documents. However, to anwer your question, I'm usually using the [rusha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rusha) lib.

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with hashing each file individually.

If two identical lines are added the combined xor will not change.

You might be better off hashing all the individual line hashes.

Perhaps use a [Merkle Tree](http://www.marcoyuen.com/articles/2014/02/01/merkle-tree.html).

Comment: It can't happen that two identical lines are added (they're unique, see question). Thanks for Merkle Tree hint, seems interesting - although *generally* I found out that hashing lots of short lines is very expensive, so probably a streaming sha1 hash (other answer) is probably better in the end

Comment: On the computers I have avaiable SHA256 will hash 400 MB/second.

Comment: ...and mobile phones? ;)

Comment: iPhone 6s: 400MB/s, iPhone4s (4 years old): 40MB/s

Comment: with JavaScript? What implementation?

Comment: I do not have any numbers for Javascript. If the actual implementation is in JaveScript it will probably be horrible, even implemented in a compiled language I see a 200:1 speed decrease over using the native iOS implementation. Android is more problematic WRT hardware support of encryption across models/versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform incremental updates to like-stream calculation:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
shasum.update("Hello, ");
shasum.update("World!");
console.log(shasum.digest('hex'));

shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
shasum.update("Hello, World!")
console.log(shasum.digest('hex'));
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Perhaps you tell me something about the XOR approach described above, too?

Comment: Your `xor` approach is something wrong. `a xor b xor b == a`. I think also, you'll never get equality of`sha1('abcd') == foo(sha1('abc'), 'd')`. It's looks like near impossible.

Comment: note that 'a xor b xor a' could never happen since all lines are unique

Comment: I was going to suggest this. I don't think the browser WebCrypto API provides this flexibility (and Safari doesn't support that yet anyway), but any implementation of the SHA-1 Merkle-Damgard construction should be fairly easily to modify to be streamable, and the efficiency gains of doing this incrementally should outweigh the slightly inefficiencies of JITting up your JavaScript crypto. With respect to the security of this approach, you would really be better off asking on Crypto.SE, but by my understanding this should be safe (assuming unique lines) for most practical threats.